# parseLong NumberFormatException on seemingly valid long

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I ran my code which has been working well so far, but has run into a weird error. The piece of code that has gone wrong takes a 'field' from an input string and converts it to a long.

The input string when the exception was thrown - this is as copied from the command line. I'm unable to get the actual string from the file since the input file is 144GB and i'm not looking for that! Everything seems to look normal though. In the file, the elements should be tab delimited.

```
SBL_XSMJR247_ID:2331788_    99  mm17    35305666    70  89M =35305769   190 NNGTCTTGGAGATCACGAGGCCCATGACAGCATGGAACAAGTCATGTGAAGCCCAGCCAGACACGATGAAAAATTTATAGACAAAAAGA   ~~JGIIJJ@CFGIJJJJIJJIJJJIEIGJJIJJJJJJJHIJIJIIFIIJJJHFHH?DFFCACEEDDDDDDDDBBDDDEEDDDDDDDD@B   xl:i:35305666   xr:i:35305754   xs:i:89 xd:A:f  xm:A:u  xa:A:"" xL:i:35305666   xR:i:35305855   xS:i:190xW:i:14 xP:i:0  xQ:i:0  xC:A:"" xD:A:"" PG:Z:novoalign  AS:i:12 UQ:i:12 NM:i:2  MD:Z:0G0C87 PQ:i:18 SM:i:70 AM:i:70
```

The error message which is thrown:

```
nfeerror: For input string: "35305666" xL
```

Yes it's a bit ugly..

Finally the code that was run to produce the error.

```
 /** Searches the input line and returns the last element of the field, i.e xL:i:20 returns 20.
 * @param line line to search
 * @param field fieldName
 * @return long field value
 */
private long findValueLong(String line, String field) {
    try {
        String[] lineComps = line.split("\t");

        for (String component : lineComps) {
            if (component.startsWith(field)) {
                return Long.parseLong(component.split(":")[component.split(":").length - 1]);
            }
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("nfe error: " + nfe.getMessage() + " " +  field);
        System.out.println(line);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return 0L;
}
```

The message thrown implies that the code found the long part of the xL field correctly -> "35305666" but it seems to have been unable to parse the result. The value is much, much less than the maximum value for a long, so it can't be that.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Update 1:**

I've added some more println statements and re-run the code to see exactly what is being parsed.I've added:

```
 System.out.println(component)
 System.out.println(component.split...) // the bit after the second ':'
```

The values returned for the two statements are:

```
xL:i:35305666
35305666
```

I've cross-referenced the values with the file and there are no hidden non-printing characters. The value appears as `...\txL:i:35305666\t...` I've now added a .trim() to the end of the function which gets the final value to parse, and am re-running the code again.. let's see what happens!

**Update 2:**

Adding `.trim()` to end of the string which is being parsed seems to have solved the issue. The split function must have been adding whitespace somewhere in the string? This is very strange behaviour though since i'm running ~160 million of these lines through and the error only occurred once. There's nothing special about this line, and it was generated in the same way as the rest. `trim()` seems like more of a workaround than a solution...

Comment: Look at the value of the string with a debugger (or with `Arrays.toString(string.toCharArray())`, and look for any mysterious extra commas). You may find there are non-printing characters in there.

Comment: I wish I could.. my IDE is install on a 256 GB hard drive, and the input file is 144GB + it needs at least twice that again for various splitting operations in the program.

Comment: Did you try simply doing a sysout on what you hand to the `Long.parseLong`? Maybe for some reason it's not what you would expect.

Comment: Then add a `System.out.println`. I mean, if you can't debug your code, you're stuck.

Comment: You should be able to extract the problematic line from the file in order to provide a [mcve] - or at least use the debugger.

Comment: I'm running it at the moment with a new println to try to determine the issue.

Comment: BTW: `Long.parseLong(component.substring(component.lastIndexOf(':') + 1))` would be a lot more memory efficient than splitting, and splitting again to find the number of things in the split.

Comment: Debug it, what could be simpler?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll refactor that.